# Cannot login linkedin on iphone using javascript api

Tags: javascript, rest, linkedin-api

I built a webapp that using linkedin api. When I using iphone, the linkedin login popup page cannot show out. I realized this problem is not only happened on me.

[Here](https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/javascript-api-ever-going-work-iphoneipad-etc) is the same problem. The solution they said is using REST API instead of Javascript API. I am just wondering is that possible to use REST API only for login, and then use Javascript API to do other things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is possible to [exchange JSAPI tokens for REST API tokens](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/exchange-jsapi-tokens-rest-api-oauth-tokens), the reverse is not possible. As the JSAPI authorization step, which sets the bearer tokens, requires the unsuported popup, there is no way to set the JS tokens.

The solution would be to use the REST API to make the calls needed.

Comment: Thanks very much for reply. My app is almost finished, and all api I used is javascript api. I do not want to change to REST API, because that will cause a lot of changes.
I found out a solution, although that may not right way. I just redirect user to touch.www.linkedin.com to login their account and then go back to my app. I know that is weird. But it at least doesn't need to change too much code for me.  Thanks again for reply.

Comment: BY redirecting to touch.www.linkedin.com, it sets a credentials cookie in the browser - note that sending someone there does NOT authorize your app to access their network, as that is still done through the REST API in your setup, but interesting workaround.

Comment: Thanks for remind me. Yes, that may be a security leak. That can only be a temporary solution. Thanks reply!